# How do I add a NextJS app to a development cluster url?

Tags: kubernetes, next.js, configuration, kubernetes-ingress, kong

In a Nextjs app, I updated `next.config.js` to include:

`module.exports = { basePath: '/project-name', };`

I made this change for the following reasons:

1. My `ingress.yaml` has that `path` listed below:

   - ```
     apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
     kind: Ingress
     metadata:
       name: project-name-ingress
       annotations:
         konghq.com/plugins: public
         konghq.com/strip-path: "true"
     spec:
       ingressClassName: kong-gateway
       rules:
         - http:
             paths:
             - path: /project-name/
               pathType: Prefix
               backend:
                 service:
                   name: project-name
                   port:
                     number: 3000
     ```
2. When I tried to access: `https://kong.k8s.development.{region}.{company}.cloud/{project-name}`, I got back an empty UI despite a successful fetch of `index.html`. Each of `html`'s chunk requests failed. It requested paths like: `/_next/static/chunks/{hash}.js`.

   - When I searched in the browser search bar `https://kong.k8s.development.{region}.{company}.cloud`**`/project-name/`**`_next/static/chunks/{hash}.js`, I did get back data, mainly because it included the **`project-name`** in the url. That's why I updated `next.config.js` to include that basePath.

However, after merging the change of the `basePath` in `next.config.js`, the path did update to include `project-name` but now even the fetching for the first file (index.html) fails.

I get back:

Request URL: `https://kong.k8s.development.{region}.{company}.cloud/{project-name}/`

Request Method: GET Status Code: 404 Not Found

In the `response` section, I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="preload" href="/project-name/_next/static/media/{hash}.p.woff2" as="font" crossorigin="" type="font/woff2"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/project-name/_next/static/css/{hash}.css" data-precedence="next"/>
        <link rel="preload" as="script" fetchPriority="low" href="/project-name/_next/static/chunks/webpack-{hash}.js"/>
        <script src="/project-name/_next/static/chunks/{hash}.js" async=""></script>
        <script src="/project-name/_next/static/chunks/{hash}.js" async=""></script>
        <script src="/project-name/_next/static/chunks/main-app-{hash}.js" async=""></script>
        <script src="/project-name/_next/static/chunks/{hash}.js" async=""></script>
        <script src="/project-name/_next/static/chunks/app/layout-{hash}.js" async=""></script>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex"/>
        <title>PROJECT Title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="/logo.svg"/>
        <meta name="next-size-adjust"/>
        <script src="/project-name/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-{hash}.js" noModule=""></script>
    </head>
    <body class="__className_{hash}">
        // {...more <script> tags...}
    </body>
</html>
```

What is going wrong? Why is it that now even the first file is returning a 404, along with every chunk? Searching for every chunk in the browser fails.

How do I successfully load up and access the app with the url: `https://kong.k8s.development.{region}.{company}.cloud/{project-name}/`?

I tried to resolve the issue by adding the basePath, but it didn't solve the issue...